# How to setup windows server 2012 NIC settings with 2 NICs?

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, amazon-vpc

I have 3 subnets created in a Amazon VPC.

Database private: 10.60.1.0/24
Application private 10.60.2.0/24
Public 10.60.3.0/24

I would like to have limited internet access to a server in the application subnet, so I created a elastic network interface in the Public subnet, assigned it a public ip address and attached it to the server.

Now I am able to see the server from the internet, but I am not able to see the database from the server.

How do I configure the NICs and/or routing to allow the server to be seen on the internet but also allow that same server to see the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do for routing in this situation.

There are a few area's you'll need to apply your security settings to allow traffic to flow from APPLICATION to DATABASE.

### Network ACLs

Ingress and Engress rules are applied to each subnet. You need to make sure you allow traffic OUT on the application subnet and IN on the database subnet. You can lock this down to specific ip and port.

### Security Groups

Inbound and Outbound rules are applied to each EC2(server)/RDS(database). You need to make sure you allow traffic OUT on the application server and IN on the database server.

### Elastic Network Interface ENI

If you're using an ENI it will have a security group applied to it.

### OS Security

Your operating system may have it's own firewall (linux has iptables for example). Windows may have it own firewall applied.